# AS3 Multitouch Input Mode GESTURE & TOUCH_POINT

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, multi-touch

how can I use Multitouch.inputMode=MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE & Multitouch.inputMode=MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT; together?

All my buttons need TOUCH_TAP, but some of the object like gallery I need some gesture like swipe/flick.

I've try to put both GESTURE & TOUCH_POINT in my Main constructor but it seem the multitouch is not function anymore.

Any solutions/suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular mouse events for tap.

Comment: WIll it be any issue if I deploy for multitouch devices?

Comment: No. For a more refined gesture implementation you can also look at the org.gestouch project.

Comment: @pizza0502 it will be an issue if you want several touches(taps) to be recognized at the same time, since mouse events are fired for the first touch only. Also I strongly do not recommend using swipe gesture for a gallery since it's a discrete gesture, which means it won't give immediate and continuous feedback to UI and user resulting in bad UX. If you're interested in multitouch development - yes, take a look at my library Gestouch.